# When a file is copied on NTFS the Modified Date is also copied?

Tags: windows, ntfs

I need to know if I can trust the Modified Date attribute of a file, there is any way to make a file seem older than it truly is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot trust any of the date/time stamps on a file.  It is relatively straightforward to [change the timestamps](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-change-the-last-modified-date-creation-date-and-last-accessed-date-for-files-and-folders/)

Comment: I've deliberately changed the last-modified date on files to keep certain people happy. You definately cannot trust it, at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can't trust it - there are tools (such as 'touch') which allow you to set such file metadata.

http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/touch.1.asp

Comment: touch(1) being a standard command in all Unix/Linux/BSD distributions that I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) command line which copies the modify date from the original file. Also there are a [GUI tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.11.utilityspotlight.aspx) for robocopy.

Comment: Also only vista supplied robocopy preserves folder dates.